# Cycling computers fits on any wheel size?

Tags: bike-computer

I'm a newbie and I plan to buy cycling computer for my bike with 29" x 2.1 wheel.

Is it all cycling computers can fit on any wheel size?

I'm planning to buy Cateye Micro Wireless MC100w or Cateye Velo 7 online. Does them fit my 29" x 2.1 wheel?

Comment: Yes, it will fit.  (Though note that in the docs that come with the computer your wheel may be listed as a 700x55c, or you may have to measure it yourself.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Cateye [CC-MC100W](http://www.cateye.com/en/products/detail/CC-MC100W/moreinfo/) site, it supports "Tire size： 100mm～3999mm". The Velo 7 supports 100cm～299cm.

29 inch * 25.4mm/inch * 3.14 = 2313mm.

So both computers will be fine.

Note that "tire size" in this case means outside circumference rather than diameter. Sheldon Brown has an exhaustive discussion but the easy way to find out is a [roll out test](http://sheldonbrown.com/cyclecomputer-calibration.html#rollout) (pick a mark on the floor, roll the wheel a complete revolution, measure)

Comment: @mattnz Thanks for expanding my rudimentary answer

Answer (score 7):

Every bike computer you'll ever use has some initial setup where you choose the units, set the time and enter either a wheel size or circumference.

Cateye's take a circumference and there's a handy chart in both manuals to help you choose one, or you can measure it.

- [Micro Wireless](http://cateye.com/images/manual/CC-MC100W_ENG_v4.pdf)
- [Velo 7](http://www.cateye.com/images/manual/CC-VL820520%20HP_ENG%20v1.pdf)

Comment: Measuring is generally thought to be more accurate. It should be done with the tires at normal pressure, with you and the usual load on the bike, as compressing the tires effectively makes the measured circumference slightly smaller.

Comment: As an addendum, newer, smarter (GPS-enabled) devices can set themselves up and furthermore can store the profiles of several bikes so the computer itself can be interchanged.